# logarithmic differential: compute $t(t+1)(t+2)\cdots(t+n-1)$

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives

While I was reading the Flajolet & Sedgewick's "Analytic Combinatorics" book, on page 121-122. I found this deduction --

$p_{n,k}$ is the probability of having $k$ cycles from a permutations of $n$ items $p_{n,k} = \frac{1}{n!}\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{n}{k}$

then the book finds a way to count all the Stirling's cycle number for a certain $n$:

$\sum_{k=0}^n\genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{n}{k}u^k = u(u+1)(u+2)\cdots(u+n-1)$

Now, the expected number of cycles is $\mu_n = \sum_k k\,p_{n,k}$

Up to this point, everything is fine. Now, the book says that $\mu_n$ is a harmonic series:

$\mu_n = H_n \equiv 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n}$

I do not understand how do I supposed to get $H_n$ from $\mu_n$.

It will be helpful to know how to deduce it.

Comment: Hint: Take logs, then differentiate with respect to $u$, then set $u=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **awkward** suggested in the comments, take the log of the polynomial in $u$ and differentiate. Taking the log gives you

$$\ln\sum_{k=0}^n{n\brack k}u^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ln(u+k)\;,$$

and differentiating then gives you

$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^n{n\brack k}u^k\right)^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^nk{n\brack k}u^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{u+k}\;,$$

or

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk{n\brack k}u^{k-1}=\left(\sum_{k=0}^n{n\brack k}u^k\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{u+k}\;.\tag{1}$$

Now let $u=1$ in $(1)$ and do a little simplifying, and you’ll have your result.